# unique_ptr to a derived class as an argument to a function that takes a unique_ptr to a base class and take owenership

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I have already read various comments similar to this question here on stack overflow without finding exactly the solution to my problem.
I have a Base class and Derived class an also a class that contain and also keep the ownership of this objects.

```cpp
class Base { };
class Derived: public Base { };

class MyClass
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> myVector;
public:
  MyClass() {}

  void addElement (std::unique_ptr<Base> &base)
  {
    myVector.push_back(std::move(base));
  }
};
```

My code fails to compile when I try to add a derived object in my class.

```cpp
MyClass myClass;

auto b = std::make_unique<Base>();
myClass.addElement(b);

auto d = std::make_unique<Derived>();
myClass.addElement (d); // <-- ERROR: error: cannot convert ‘std::unique_ptr >’ to ‘std::unique_ptr&’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function must accept the `unique_ptr` by value:

```
  void addElement (std::unique_ptr<Base> base)
  {
    myVector.push_back(std::move(base));
  }
```

and then call the member function like this:

```
MyClass myClass;

auto b = std::make_unique<Base>();
myClass.addElement(std::move(b));

auto d = std::make_unique<Derived>();
myClass.addElement(std::move(d));
```

or even better avoid the variables because you cannot use them anyway after the function call:

```
MyClass myClass;

myClass.addElement(std::make_unique<Base>());

myClass.addElement(std::make_unique<Derived>());
```

Comment: So, to have to make it works I have to move the unique_ptr twice? This is the best solution?
I can't create it directly in the function call because I have to set some other variables.

Comment: You can remove one actual move by declaring the parameter `unique_ptr<Base>&&`, but then you must cast the pointer-to-Derived to pointer-to-Base explicitly: `addElement(std::unique_ptr<Base>(std::move(d))`. The move that is implied here you cannot avoid.

Comment: Or you make `addElement` a function template that just forwards to `myvector.emplace_back`. You must still use `std::move` at the call sites.

Comment: @AGheller: Recall that `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, it qualifies a reference type in order to match moving operations.